# Drupal 8 Image Styles Not Generating - LEMP on CentOS 7

Tags: media, 8

- Centos 7
- Nginx 1.10.2
- PHP Version 7.1.5
- Database 5.5.52-MariaDB
- Drupal 8.3.2

I have exhausted just about every possible google result and every forum post I can feasibly find. Thank you in advance for any help you can offer me.

**PROBLEM:**
Images are uploading to the appropriate folders under /sites/default/files/WHATEVER-SUBDIRECTORY

Image styles are not generating under the /styles folder and I am getting broken images whenever they should appear on-page.

**I HAVE TRIED:**

- Rewriting my Nginx config.
- Setting all permissions to 777 (for testing purposes).
- Adding $conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE; to
  settings.php.
- All directories and files are owned by the correct user/group.
- Flushing cache as well as image stores.
- The only type of errors I have been able to find are in my nginx
  access.log: "GET
  /sites/default/files/styles/large/public/2017-05/my_image.jpg?itok=Ax9jzc70
  HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://mysite.mysite.come/node/1" "Mozilla/5.0
  (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
  Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36" "-"Safari/537.36" "-"

**nginx.conf:**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name     mysite.mysite.com;
        root /var/www/drupal;
        ssl_certificate SSL CERT HERE;
        ssl_certificate_key SSL CERT KEY HERE;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:100m;
        ssl_session_timeout 30m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location / {
        try_files       $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
        deny    all;
        return  404;
    }

    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found   off;

    }

    location ~* /sites/.*/files/styles { # For Drupal >= 7
        access_log      off;
        expires         max;
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }
    }

server {
listen       80 default_server;
server_name  mysite.mysite.com;
root         /var/www/drupal;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
}
```

Everything else seems to be working like a dream, but I can't for the life of me seem to figure out these image styles. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: You may try this pattern `location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ ` instead of `location ~* /sites/.*/files/styles` . Also have a look at styles and subfolders permissions, and give `rwx` permission to nginx user (in most cases, www-data, be with apache or nginx)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately this didn't work. Tried the suggested nginx config change and set all permissions recursively to 777 throughout the entire drupal deployment (for testing purposes). :-/

Comment: I finally found a solution to this problem! As it turns out, systemd is configured to give php-fpm a private /tmp. I had to edit the .service file to set PrivateTmp=false. It is worth noting that if you're running multiple sites on of the same server, PrivateTmp should be set to =true for security reasons. **[For reverence, here is the thread that saved my rump in the end.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444914/php-has-its-own-tmp-in-tmp-systemd-private-nabcde-tmp-when-accessed-through-ng)** Thanks again.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it turns out it was because mod_rewrite wasn't enabled in apache2

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem to yours, and found out that to image URL was added "?h=xxxxxxx&" before "itok=", so after deleting this string and pasting URL in browsers, these files were created without any problems.

The only way I found out how to remove this strings from being added was to add in settings.local.php (or settings.php depend on how You config your website) this line:

`$config['image.settings']['allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;`

Answer (score 0):

as for me, this one was caused by nginx config issue
just replace "location" directive with one below:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }
```

and reload nginx
`sudo systemctl start nginx` ( on cent os )

it helped me

rights on `sites/default/files` 775
owner `nginx`

Answer (score 0):

inside de `server` you have to add rewrite rule and use it inside assets location. You can see bellow:

```
server {
    # MY OTHER NGINX SERVER CONFFS GOES HERE

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```